# Golang best way of calling/invoking sub project

Tags: go

Im moving my project from `PHP` to `Golang` and I looking efficient way of calling/invoking/handling control to `sub project` `main.go` from `src` `main.go`,  I want to pass control from

```
http://localhost/  =>   http://localhost/sub-project1/
http://localhost/  =>   http://localhost/sub-project2/
http://localhost/  =>   http://localhost/sub-projectn/
```

I'm new to `Golang` I don't know how to do it in best way, and my project structure is

```
src/
    main.go
    sub-project1/
        main.go
    sub-project2/
        main.go
    sub-projectn/
        main.go
    gitHub.com/
        ......
    golang.org/
        ......
```

I'm using `httprouter` for routing, in `main.go` which is located under `src` contain following

```
package main
import ....

// homePageHandler
// contactPageHandler
// aboutPageHandler
// loginPageHandler
// signupPageHandler

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", homePageHandler)
    router.GET("/contact", contactPageHandler)
    router.GET("/about", aboutPageHandler)
    router.GET("/login", loginPageHandler)
    router.GET("/signup", signupPageHandler)

    // here I want to pass control to my sub project main.go 
    // and I don't want to write any /sub-project routing urls here,
    // because each /sub-project's contain many urls 
    router.GET("/sub-project1", ??????)
    router.GET("/sub-project2", ??????)
    router.GET("/sub-project3", ??????)
    router.GET("/sub-projectn", ??????)
}
```

and all files must be passes from `src` `main.go` because whole project has only one `main()` and inside any `/sub-projectx` `main.go` I want to do this

```
package main
import ....
// subprojectPageHandler
// feature1PageHandler
// feature2PageHandler
// feature3PageHandler
// ........
// featurenPageHandler

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/sub-projectx", subprojectPageHandler)
    router.GET("/sub-projectx/feature1", feature1PageHandler)
    router.GET("/sub-projectx/feature2", feature2PageHandler)
    router.GET("/sub-projectx/feature3", feature3PageHandler)
    ..........
    router.GET("/sub-projectx/featureN", featureNPageHandler)


    // here I want to pass control to my sub project main.go 
    // and I don't want to write any /sub-project routing urls here,
    // because each /sub-project's contain many urls 
    router.GET("/sub-project1", ??????)
    router.GET("/sub-project2", ??????)
    router.GET("/sub-project3", ??????)
    router.GET("/sub-projectn", ??????)
}
```

Comment: 1. There are no "sub-projects" in Go (for whatever notion of sub-project you might choose). 2. You can have handlers for URL paths like /subproject1/whatever in any package you import into your executable. So just make a package which supplies one HTTP handler "per subproject" and route to this handler from your main. 3. Folder structure is not relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

**To be**

*Golang* source code is not running through interpreter, but is built into a binary, which gives less flexibility in case of dynamic projects. That said, I'd keep my projects isolated one from another, and would let *Nginx* (for example) take care of multiple project grouping. Of course, that would require some refactoring like creating shared packages, etc.

**Or not to be**

If, for some reason, you still think running multiple projects via single binary is ok, it's your choice. In this case you might have a look into route grouping that are available in some frameworks. Here's [what Go Gin provides](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#grouping-routes):

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    // Simple group: v1
    v1 := router.Group("/v1")
    {
        v1.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
        v1.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
        v1.POST("/read", readEndpoint)
    }

    // Simple group: v2
    v2 := router.Group("/v2")
    {
        v2.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
        v2.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
        v2.POST("/read", readEndpoint)
    }

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Comment: Of course, you might want those group routes to be created in your sub-projects via function call, i.e. `project1.init_routes(v1)`